Can't change text box font size in GIMP on macOS
I added a text box to a GIMP project in a new layer. I can select it and a panel shows up with the text properties (here it's out of the main image, but there is text in it):

But when I change the font size in the top right, the text's size doesn't change. If I hit enter, nothing happens. When I leave the panel (with escape or by selecting something else), then open that panel again, the font size goes back to the original value.
What am I doing wrong? How to validate my input so the font size actually changes?

The font options that show up on canvas are for "ephemeral" changes: they will change the attributes of selected text that's already written, and, with some practice can change what one is about to type, but clicking on wrong places will reset them.
Selecting attributes on the tool options dialogue, on the other hand will change the attributes of the text tool for the whole block and won't revert back.
This behavior has to do with historical roots in the software - people are working in making it more intuitive in the future.

Honestly just a label above the popup saying "these settings are ephemeral, see the side panel to change text properties" would be enough :)

Changing the font size in the side panel works:

I just found this after posting the question. Not sure why the popup panel didn't work.
